# How to pass the original Caller ID on Twilio? (Sip Domain Voice URL Configuration)

Tags: php, twilio, asterisk, sip, twilio-php

In short, I have a Twilio Elastic SIP Trunk and configured my PBX (Asterisk) to make outbound calls through the SIP Domain on Twilio; when logging into Twilio I have the option of configuring the SIP Domain's voice configuration URL so when a call is dialed out, the script passes the call to its destination.

For whatever reason, it used to pass the original caller ID of the person when I forward a call out but now it keeps overwriting the Caller ID with my office's number; essentially masking the original caller's caller ID when a call is transferred out; this is pretty annoying and I'm trying to figure out the best way to resolve it.

My goal is to fix outbound dialing so when a call is transferred externally, the caller ID of the individual should display instead of my office's number;

The Twiml config I have for my SIP Domain's voice URI looks like this:

```
<?php
echo header('content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$to=$_REQUEST['To'];
$callerId=$_REQUEST["callerId"];
/** Extracting user name **/
$pos1 = strpos($to,":");
$pos2 = strpos($to,"@");
$tosip=substr($to,$pos1+1,$pos2-$pos1-1);
if(strlen($tosip) == 3)
{
/**Extracting sip endpoint**/
    $pos2 = strpos($to,":",strpos($to,":")+1);
    $tosip=substr($to,$pos1+1,$pos2-$pos1-1);

    ?>
    <Response>
        <Dial>
            <Sip>
                <?php echo $tosip; ?>
            </Sip>
        </Dial>
    </Response>
    <?php } else { if(substr($tosip,0,2)=="00") $tosip=substr($tosip,2,strlen($tosip)-1); if(substr($tosip,0,3)=="011") $tosip=substr($tosip,3,strlen($tosip)-1); ?>
    <Response>
        <Dial callerId="<?php echo $callerId; ?>" >
            <?php echo $tosip; ?>
        </Dial>
    </Response>
    <?php } ?>
```

To successfully pass the call I have to make the $GET param for CallerId my office's number; but this overwrites the original caller ID; it used to be I could simply call the  verb and the original caller ID would appear; but now it doesn't seem the case.

Any advice or point in the right direction appreciated!

Comment: Twilio trunk have limited ability of cid change https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be an issue. Programmable Voice SIP Domains, require the CallerID to either be a [verified Caller ID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio) or a Twilio phone number in your account when calling out to the Public Switched Telephone Network (PSTN).

The ability to forward inbound CallerID to the outbound destination would only work from a call forwarding context (the call comes into Twilio from the PSTN and then you forward it on with a Dial verb to the PSTN as an example).

"When you use  in your response to Twilio's inbound call request, the dialed party sees the inbound caller's number as the [caller ID](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid)."